# VB.NET problem converting DataTable to JSON

Tags: vb.net, json, datatable, dataset, javascriptserializer

Ok so I'm trying to use the JavaScriptSerializer to work with [**this**](http://pastebin.com/m55eba86a) code. However it crashes when it reaches the last line;

```
Dim json As New String(sr.Serialize(dt))
```

I get this error message;

> A circular reference was detected
>   while serializing an object of type
>   'System.Reflection.Module'.

I would really appreciate any insights that could help solve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Circular reference means that serialising the object would result in an infinite loop.
For example if you would try to serialize object "A" having a 1 to 1 reference to object "B".

Declare a class containg the data you want to serialize with JSON to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

As hkda150 has already said, you could use a class specifically tailored for being serialized.

This will furthermore enable you to have foreign key values serialized instead of having related full objects serialized. Thus, if you are serializing object a which has a property a.SomeB of type B, then you will often want the ID of a.someB to be present in your webpage. Obviously I don't know enough to be able to say if this is relevant in your specific use case.

BTW, If you find yourself doing a lot of mapping between "business objects" and "objects meant for serialization" you may want to consider using [AutoMapper](http://www.codeplex.com/AutoMapper).