# serialize datatable to JSON issue vb.net

Tags: vb.net, json, serialization, datatable, javascriptserializer

Ok, I'm trying to serialize a data table in vb.net:

```
Dim dt As New System.Data.DataTable
```

and for the serializer:

```
Dim js As JavaScriptSerializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()
dim jsonString as string
jsonString=js.serialize(dt)
```

when it serialize the data table on the last line,
it got an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Extensions.dll
>
> Additional information: A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo'

I even make the simplest datatable with only 1 column and 1 row, but it just won't serialize it,

I know that this kind of question was answered: [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307605/vb-net-problem-converting-datatable-to-json)

but I don't know how to implement the answer (make a new class),
or maybe there's an even better solution?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is not out of the box serializer for DataTable objects. I ended up going with a full custom serialization. Another approach could be converting first your DataTable to an IEnumerable<> and then, serializing.

However, this link may be helpful: [JSV](http://www.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=176)